# Performance difference: initialize and override in an if-else block, or an extra "else"?

Tags: java, performance

I'm curious as to which of the following would be more efficient: initializing a variable with a default value and only overriding it if needed in an if-else block, or initializing the variable without a value at all and setting a value in that if-else block?

Here is an example of the former and latter:

Former:

```
    String weightStatus = "Underweight";

    if (bMI > 29.9)
    {
    weightStatus = "Obese";
    }

    else if (bMI >= 25.0)
    {
    weightStatus = "Overweight";
    }
    
    else if (bMI >= 18.5)
    {
    weightStatus = "Healthy Weight";
    }
```

Latter:

```
    String weightStatus;

    if (bMI > 29.9)
    {
    weightStatus = "Obese";
    }
    
    else if (bMI >= 25.0)
    {
    weightStatus = "Overweight";
    }
    
    else if (bMI >= 18.5)
    {
    weightStatus = "Healthy Weight";
    }
    else
    {
    weightStatus = "Underweight";
    }
```

The difference would be small, but I can't help but wonder which one is technically faster based on how variable assignment works.

Comment: I would go for a switch statement with a default.

Comment: Phix Obviously, but I'm not asking about switch statements.  Thank you, though.

Comment: The first one has one more assignment. By the time you factor in optimisations, predictive branching, CPU/memory speeds, etc, you definitely won't notice the difference. User whichever makes the code clearer to you.

Comment: @yshavit The first one has one *less* assignment, and one more initialization.

Comment: @Phix You can't do inequalities with a switch.

Comment: @ejp how's that? The first one has two assignments for all but underweight (the initialization counts), while the second has exactly only assignment in all branches. To clarify, I meant assignment in the "value is stored" sense. Perhaps I should have been more careful with my language.

Comment: You would need to test it with a specific version of Java on a specific platform to determine which is faster in practice; however, you could examine the byte-code and make some assumptions....

Comment: The second one allows to make the variable "final", and so it's better. And if the performance is critical then you can optimize comparisons. In the worst case you have 3 comparisons, This can be reduced to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the former case, the bytecode will always set the variable, then according to the `if/then`, it may reset it again.

But it also depends on which values would be passed at runtime, if mostly they are not in `then` branches, then I guess it won't make much difference, but if they frequently go into `then` branches, then there is mostly double setting executions.

You can test it with something like:

```
public class MyTest {

    private static double START = 0;
    private static double END = 100;
    private static double INCREMENT = 0.0001;

    @Test
    public void testFirst() throws Exception {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        for (double bMI = START; bMI < END; bMI += INCREMENT) {
            first(bMI);
        }
        System.out.println("First  " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSecond() throws Exception {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        for (double bMI = START; bMI < END; bMI += INCREMENT) {
            second(bMI);
        }
        System.out.println("Second " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
    }

    private String first(double bMI) {
        String weightStatus = "Underweight";
        if (bMI > 29.9) {
            weightStatus = "Obese";
        } else if (bMI >= 25.0) {
            weightStatus = "Overweight";
        } else if (bMI >= 18.5) {
            weightStatus = "Healthy Weight";
        }
        return weightStatus;
    }

    private String second(double bMI) {
        String weightStatus;
        if (bMI > 29.9) {
            weightStatus = "Obese";
        } else if (bMI >= 25.0) {
            weightStatus = "Overweight";
        } else if (bMI >= 18.5) {
            weightStatus = "Healthy Weight";
        } else {
            weightStatus = "Underweight";
        }
        return weightStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would initially check with the IDE, but then test the result by run it with actual expected values on the runtime (server) environment, if you have input data.

Comment: Chosen as answer because answer is clear, in depth, and provides code example. Thank you, this is awesome!

Comment: That's not a great benchmark; you don't have any warmup, for instance. You should read up on how to write a microbenchmark in Java before you draw any conclusions from a perf test. You may want to look at jmh, too.